# Flutter Execution failed for task ':app:dexBuilderDebug'

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

When i try to run my flutter project i get the "Execution failed for task ':app:dexBuilderDebug'" error.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to android>app>build.gradle and delete 'apply plugin: 'kotlin-android''

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem "`Execution failed for task ':app:dexBuilderDebug'`" running debug flutter app.

Try delete this folder  `C:\Users\USER_NAME\.gradle\caches`